# Centralize database with multiple websites

Tags: mysql, laravel-4, codeigniter-2

This is not a issue but I'm just looking for the best concept.
I have a main website at `maindomain.com` and also there are multiple subdomains like `a.maindomain.com` ,  `b.maindomain.com`, and so on.
All these subdomains represents multiple websites ( services ) as the same concept of the main  website ( slightly different). For example if a user try to use the main website or a sub service it will use one account to access all the website. So I would like to know the best method to centralize my database to be shared with all the websites, and what do you think if the UI should be (same colors, same typography ) .

My example is Google; we can use one account for multiple services such as gmail, google+, youtube, ...

By the way the main website made with Codeigniter 2 , and the others made with Laravel 4.1

Thanks for your ideas and help.

Answer (score 0):

as ur questions says the answer is itself the statcokoverflow site which maintains multiple domain on stackexchange

so for that you can use multiple tables in a **single DB along with a master table** maintaining the details of the user ,where he has visited say if he goes **to a.doamin.com** then the table should contain the entry also if he visits **b.doamin.com** then also and the sub details under that filed you can maintain **foreign** key fields to maintain data

- benefit of this will be you have all the data under one db which will be eazy to maintain users also information regrading a user can be get easily from master table that where he has visited where not .
- other benefit will be will if you data base structure is in normalized form it will help you to maintain user details with less complexities.
- also maintaining a single DB with multiple table is eazy to maintain as compared to maintaing 2 db with having table relationships.

Comment: I quite agree with you, single database is the best choice. 
It is significant to have a similar UI to make a good experience for the user?

Comment: yeah you can go for the similar UI with different colors and menus ,it will be comfortable for the user to understand and easy for you to maintain as they are being bind to main domain as sub domain so there is no harm if they look quite similar